# Android: SlidingMenu onCreateOptionsMenu not called in Fragment

Tags: android, menu, fragment, slidingmenu

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Currently, I try to add new menu item in ColorFragment of library of SlidingMenu.

However, the method `onCreateOptionsMenu` did not get called.

It's bug? Could you help to test add menu into to test class 'ColorFragment'??

Android Version: 4.1.1

Device: Tablet 7.0

```
public class ColorFragment extends Fragment {

private int mColorRes = -1;

public ColorFragment() {
    this(R.color.white);
}

public ColorFragment(int colorRes) {
    mColorRes = colorRes;
    setRetainInstance(true);


}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
 ..
 ..
 ..
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_cust, menu);
}   

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just give it a try.. Hope it will help.

set this in onCreateView()

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

and also change your onCreateOptionsMenu

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater menuInflater) {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
}
```

Comment: Thanks help. But It's also not work. you can download test project to try to add menu https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu
please focus on class ColorFragment.java

Answer (score 0):

I know it's quite old but it might help someone else.

In addition to: (In onCreate/onCreateView)

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

You should also set the action bar for the activity (In the fragment's onActivityCreated()  method is a good place):

```
//Kotlin
    (requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(mToolbar)
//Java
    ((AppCompatActivity) requireActivity()).setSupportActionBar(mToolbar)
```